# Will I be able to track progress of my referrals when transferring between regions?

Tags: league-of-legends

If I transfer to another region, will I be able to track progress of my referrals? If not, and I transfer back to my initial server region, will I be able to track progress of my referrals?

*I am interested in tracking progress of referrals (people that I have recruited) not in benefits from referrals program or my progress towards to rewards.*

Comment: Are you talking about the Refer-A-Friend Program or ingame Friends?

Comment: @Jutschge Refer-a-Friend 2.0 http://rewards.na.leagueoflegends.com/

Comment: @Othya I did not find answers to my questions in the link that you provided.

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear

Comment: Hmm it's an interesting but tricky question. Lolwiki states that `Referrals will be accepted from both EU and US; it does not matter which server they sign up with`. I don't know though what happens if you transfer an account.

Comment: @Othya Thanks for editing. I slightly corrected your edit. I am interested not in keeping benefits while transfer but in keeping tracking my referrals.

Comment: From that quote I assume that it doesn't matter, as they are not region bound

Comment: @Mathias711 Yes it appears to be... Unfortunately I'm not 100% sure.. so no answer from me.

Comment: Please someone remove "This question may already have an answer here:" Because that question is not related to my question.

Comment: do you want to track your progression towards rewards or the level of the guys you have recruited?

Comment: @gruntswilldie Thanks for your question. I want to track progress of the guys I have recruited.  I made corrections to my question.

Comment: @vasili111 Unless the question actually gets closed, which is unlikely at this point, only you are seeing that notice. It gets displayed to the asker as long as there are duplicate-votes on the question, and should vanish in a day or two, assuming it does stay open.

Comment: @Billy Mailman Thank you for information. I did not knew that

Answer (score 2):

After some deeper digging into the league-of-hard-to-find-FAQs I found [this article](https://support.leagueoflegends.com/entries/22305955-Refer-a-Friend-General-Information-RAF-2-0-#GoToTop).

It states: You will keep your referrals but if they are on a different server you won't see the level. This also means if you or a referred friend will switch servers, he will only count towards your progress if he hits level 10 while you are on the same server.

**You won't be able to see the Level of Referrals on other servers**.

[Here](https://support.leagueoflegends.com/entries/26112905-Account-Transfer-FAQ#affect) you can find the information about the things that will transfer and the ones that won't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will they become visible again if I transfer back to that server (I mean the server that I left before)?

Comment: @vasili111 I assume they will, but I'm not 100% sure. Maybe you should try to contact the [customer support](https://support.leagueoflegends.com/home) for details.