# Will I be able to track progress of my referrals if I rename summoner?

Tags: league-of-legends

If I rename summoner, will I be able to track progress of my referrals? If not, and I rename my summoner to original name back, will I be able to track progress of my referrals again?

*I am interested in tracking progress of referrals (people that I have recruited) not in benefits from referrals program or my progress towards to rewards.*

Comment: Related from you: [Will I be able to track progress of my referrals when transferring between regions?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/175046/43105)

Comment: @SysDragon These two are different questions, which should have different answers. So I did not combined them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will still be able to track your Referrals. You will only change your Summoner name (The name that's shown In-Game) and not your Account Name (The name you log in with). A Summoners Name change is basically just a "Cosmetic" Field in the database that's being altered. Since It's a Cosmetic  field and not an ID (it's still unique tho) you will keep your referrals, Friends, and everything else.

Comment: You seem to answer a lot of questions on here lol, I think we should have a game of LoL sometime. Want to see how good you are :P

Comment: @Ruddy Yeah well I'm currently taking a break from playing LoL. I kinda dislike what they did to my main roles (ADC and Support) and I dropped from Platinum 1 to Platinum 5... Basically the only thing I currently have to do with League is Theorycrafting and Coaching players...^^ I still understand how the game works but I can't really play it anymore  (and I don't want to either somehow).

Comment: You don't just become bad at LoL, i'm silver 1 (down from gold due to not playing LoL for a month... this happend 2 times now) I just want to see how "good" you think I am tbh. If you play at a high rank you will know how I can improve etc. Be nice to have help from someone higher as out of my friends that play I am the "best" player. Any time to help me out?

Comment: @Ruddy Well yeah I can analyse your playstyle but I'm not really good in showing how to do it better (only explaining). My playstyle skill is about Lower gold but my game knowledge is around Diamond ;). But I guess the main problem is that I've just uninstalled the game about a week ago. Maybe I'll reinstall it since I kinda want the End of Season Rewards.

Comment: Your plat tho, if you got there then you should be that level. Its not all about "skill" with a mouse etc. Knowledge is a huge part of playing the game well. I would very much like it if you did join me on LoL for a few games. Never know, may just find love for the game again and a new friend to game with :P

Comment: @Jutschge OFFTOP What you can tell about other MOBA games? Do you like any of them and if yes, which of them?

Comment: @vasili111 well I could tell you some things and opinions but those are rather off-topic in a comment section of a question ;). You can still join me and others in [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) where discussions are allowed.

Comment: @Jutschge Not enough reputation to be able to use that chat :(   . Does http://gaming.stackexchange.com/ has its own chat? Or may be you use IRC?